# Why did Richard's cleaning lady keep throwing out the S-Z phone book?

Tags: douglas-adams, dirk-gently

From chapter 16 of *Dirk Gently's Holistic Detective Agency*:

> There was no Gently at all.  Not a single one.  He found the other directories, except for the S-Z book which his cleaning lady continually threw away for reasons he had never yet fathomed.

Is this just a throwaway bit of random nonsense, or is there a hidden meaning?

Comment: knowing Adams - probably both